# IIS website only allowing https connection, no http

Tags: https, http, iis, firewall, port-number

We are running two websites on IIS (`site1.site.example` and `site2.site.example`).

Both sites have the same bindings but with different host names (as above), on IP address `*` and for ports 80 and 443 (HTTP and HTTPS respectively).

`site1` is externally accessible via both protocols, however `site2` will only work via HTTPS. Curiously, if I go to SSL Settings the 'Require SSL' box is unchecked and Client certificates set to 'Ignore'.

What do I change to allow `site2` to be accessible via HTTP (secure connection is actually not required at all)

Comment: Incidently, about "secure connection is actually not required at all": browsers will soon display all HTTP connections as Insecure in address bar. So while not technically required, it may frighten visitors...

Comment: I was thinking about this. Currently the SSL cert is specifically for site1, so if I use it for site2 it displays the invalid warning. Would I be able to 'convert' that cert to a wildcard for *.site.com or should I purchase a 2nd cert for site2

Comment: *Would I be able to 'convert' that cert to a wildcard for *.site.com or should I purchase a 2nd cert for site2*  both technically work and provide same results, so it is more a matter of personal choices and other external constraints - regarding configuration, renewals, etc... - , and you even have a third choice: a certificate with both `site1` and `site2` explicitely as names in it, it is called `SAN` for Server Alternate Name. A wildcard may be better if you intend to extend to `site3`, etc. later but may be more costly, if you do not use Let's Encrypt.

Comment: What happens when you request site2 without Https? Do you get site1, or some other error message? Without more information it's a little hard to debug.

Comment: Can you run Binding Diagnostics on site2 and reveal what the report says? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html It should tell the basic information you need, and if you paste that here, others might help you better.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue due to misspelling the domain binding for http.  I spelled it correctly for https an so it appeared that I had some sort of misconfiguration, but it was just a stupid type-o.  Five hours of debugging, down the drain.